# Globals Not Passing Variables Trough Functions Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Im trying to pass a variable setting like this:
gingerlu

Comment: It might help if you show us the whole code. This seems like half-code, half-pseudocode. what is "recap"? Is it the same as "Recap()"?

Comment: @hikerjobs edited

Comment: There is far too much code; please reduce the code to the essentials, such that it is still a standalone example. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Note that your code has functions within functions, and uses global variables. That is generally not done in Python, as it can easily lead to spaghetti- or otherwise unmaintainable (and unsound) code. The fact that the indentation is irregular (including syntax errors; see the `try:` directly below `main():`), doesn't help.

Comment: You might want to [find a good python tutorial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/Programmers) to get a better feel of what python code should look like.

Answer (score 1):

`global` variable won't be problem.

```
In [1]: def recap():
   ...:     global pos
   ...:     pos = 100
   ...:

In [2]: def main():
   ...:     recap()
   ...:     print(pos)
   ...:

In [3]: main()
100
```

The main reason is that you use a local varible `pos` in you `main()` function, it's not global.